# How to sort an abstract collection by the implementation classes?

Tags: java, sorting

I have a `Collection<BasePerson>`, where BasePerson is an `abstract` class sharing common properties.

```
abstract class BasePerson {
    String name;
}

class Person extends BasePerson {

}

class Employee extends BasePerson {
    int id;
}
```

How can I sort the collection by type? I want to have Any `Person` to be sorted by `name` and on top of any "non-person" classes.

The `Employee` objects themself should be sorted first by `id`, then by `name`

Input:

```
#name;id
xava (Person)
anna,31 (Employee)
tom,30 (Employee)
```

output:

```
xava (persons before employees)
tom,30 (id should have a higher weight than name comparison)
anna,31
```

How can I create such a `Comparator<Person>`?

```
new Comparator<BasePerson>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(BasePerson p1, BasePerson p2) {
        if (p1 instanceof Person) {
            if (p2 instanceof Person) {
                return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());    
            }

            return 1;
        } else if (p2 instanceof Person) {
            return -1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to add the instance based comparison parts to the comparator.

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: See comment above. Comparing the name is easy, but how coudl I add the instanceof here? Especially, how can I sort `Person` types on top of `Employee` ?

Comment: Have you tried using the `instanceof`operator? (In combination with type casts)

Comment: how can `"weka"` or `"tom"` be attributes of type `int name`?

Comment: Yes I've tried, see edit above. But I don't know if that is the "right" way to achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: This is a good task for test driven development (tdd).
Write your test with all possible combinations you can think of.
Keep in mind the rules for a Comparator : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html .Then start implementing the Comparator.

Comment: @TobiasOtto Thank you for recommending TDD. It's difficult at first but incredibly rewarding. I also encourage the poster to give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

The comparator algorithm can be easy if you think in numbers.
For example: `int n = 1` and `int m = 2` the default behaviour of `Integer.compare(n,m)`
do `(n < m) ? -1 : ((n == m) ? 0 : 1)` and returns `-1` because `n` (first parameter) is lower than `m` (second parameter). So, when the first parameter is lower than the second parameter, the comparator should returns a negative integer value.

If `n = 3` and `m = 0`, it returns `1` because `m` (second parameter) is lower than `n` (first parameter). when the first parameter is greater than the second parameter, the comparator should returns a positive integer value.

If `n = 1` and `m = 1`, it returns `0` because both are equals.

You have two mistakes:

```
new Comparator<BasePerson>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(BasePerson p1, BasePerson p2) {
            if (p1 instanceof Person) {
                if (p2 instanceof Person) {
                    return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
                }
                return -1; // <--------------------------------- here is mistake-1
            } else if (p2 instanceof Person) {
                return 1; // <---------------------------------- here is mistake-2
            }
            // Employee comparator:
            if (p1 instanceof Employee && p2 instanceof Employee) {
                Employee e1 = (Employee) p1;
                Employee e2 = (Employee) p2;
                if (e1.id == e2.id) {
                    return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
                } else {
                    return Integer.compare(e1.id, e2.id);
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    };
```

Mistake-1: If `p1` is lower than `p2`, because (`p1` is an instance of person and `p2` is not) you returned `1` and It is a positive integer! You are saying that `p2` is lower than `p1`.

Mistake-2: If `p1` is greater than `p2`, because (`p1` is not an instance of person and `p2` is it) you returned `-1` and It is a negative integer! You are saying that `p1` is lower than `p2`.

EDIT:

I Added the employee comparator.

Comment: also the final `return 0` should be `return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());`

Comment: @Onheiron It isn't, the criteria to compare Employees is different. Edited for this.

Comment: What I don't understand: if `p1=Person` and `p2 != Person`, I'd like to have the order `p1, p2`. Why then should I return a `-1`, and not a `+1`?

Comment: Because if it returns `-1` You are saying that the first parameter is lower than the second, And the sorting is ascending. Then `p1` will be before than `p2`